# Cloudstack on Debian

Tags: debian, apache-cloudstack

Has anyone tried to use Cloudstack on Debian (wheezy or Jessie)?

I'm installing the management server according with the [documentation][1] and everything goes quite well until I try to setup the management service:

```
$ cloudstack-setup-management
Starting to configure CloudStack Management Server:
Error: CloudStack failed to detect your operating system. Exiting.
```

The logs under `/var/log/cloudstack/management` are hopeless (and empty) and I cannot find any reference/workaround for this issue.

It is worth to mention that instructions are for CentOS and Ubuntu.

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to actually link to which documentation you were following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved on [**this**](https://reviews.apache.org/r/9310/) patch

Answer (score 0):

You need to install lsb-release

```
sudo apt install lsb-release
```